# Django Database router based on user selection

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-admin

I'm writing a django project that will require me to route queries to 
certain large databases based on the user selection.

So all the tables for django.contrib.auth and session and stuff will be 
in the 'central' database, as well as a table that maps users to which 
database they need to use for the main app.

Can you help me come up with a way of routing database queries this way 
using a Django database router?

Log in user form has the database selection option.If the user is a valid user , then he will be connected to the his selected DB

At the start of the view could I take the logged in user from 
request.user or wherever it is, and some how provide that variable to my 
database router for the rest of the request?

All suggestions welcome.