# Django has multiple databases and each database has its own group of applications

Tags: python, django, database, postgresql, routes

I have a group of Django applications need to be placed in its own Postgres database instance

Let say I have `app1, app2, app3, app4, app5, app6`. And I have multiple database instances for them

```
DATABASES = {
    "default": env.db("DATABASE_URL", default="postgres://postgres:postgres@localhost:5432/th_life"),
    "analytic": env.db("ANALYTIC_URL", default="postgres://postgres:postgres@localhost:5432/th_life_analytic"),
    "product": env.db("PRODUCT_URL", default="postgres://postgres:postgres@localhost:5432/th_life_product"),
    "customer": env.db("CUSTOMER_URL", default="postgres://postgres:postgres@localhost:5432/th_life_customer"),
}
```

For sake of simplicity I will give an short example `default and customer`
I need `app1, app2, and app3` go to `customer` database instance

```
class DBRouter(object):

    def __init__(self):
        print(f"Customize router")
        super().__init__()

    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
        # customer information
        if model._meta.app_label in ['app1', 'app2', 'app3']:
            return 'customer'
        return None

    def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
        if model._meta.app_label in ['app1', 'app2', 'app3']:
            return 'customer'
        return None

    def allow_relation(self, obj1, obj2, **hints):
        if obj1._meta.app_label in ['app1', 'app2', 'app3'] or \
            obj2._meta.app_label in ['app1', 'app2', 'app3']:
            return True
        return None

    def allow_migrate(self, db, app_label, model_name=None, **hints):
        if app_label in ['app1', 'app2', 'app3']:
            return db == 'customer'
        return None
```

After I tried `migrate` `app1`. It is not apply schema to the target database. It goes to `default` database instance

**Question:**
What is the correct way to group my applications to particular database instance?

**References:**
I had tried some of them and many of them are outdated or no answers

[Official docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/multi-db/#topics-db-multi-db-routing)

[multiple databases and multiple models in django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18547468/multiple-databases-and-multiple-models-in-django)

[Django Database router based on user selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14332631/django-database-router-based-on-user-selection)

[django database routing with transactions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17169971/django-database-routing-with-transactions)

[Dynamic database routing in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22362216/dynamic-database-routing-in-django)

[Django migrations router databases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49683539/django-migrations-router-databases)

[Django database router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9653449/django-database-router)

[Different database for each django site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12352360/different-database-for-each-django-site/12353583#12353583)

[Configure Django Database Routers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44009504/configure-django-database-routers)

[Django multi-database routing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8054195/django-multi-database-routing)

[multiple databases and multiple models in django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18547468/multiple-databases-and-multiple-models-in-django)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad. I have to specify `migrate --database=customer` Otherwise `migration` will not run on the other database instances!